# To delete loop inside a variable using powershell

Tags: json, powershell

[image]

I did invoke-restmethod and stored the output in variable $a and used convertTo-json and i want to remove the variables and values which are not required.
  I have used $a -replace "variables" -replace "value" but it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to manipulate JSON *as text* (as a string).

It's easier and more robust to transform the _objects (`[pscustomobject]` instances) representing the input JSON that [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) returns:

```
# Assume that $fromJson was obtained as follows:
#   $fromJson = Invoke-RestMethod ...

$fromJson.variables | ForEach-Object {
  # Replace the property values with the current value's .value property
  # value.
  foreach ($prop in $_.psobject.Properties) {
    $_.($prop.Name) = $prop.Value.value
  }
  $_  # Output the modified object.
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

`$json.variables` uses [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) to return an array of the `variables` property values, and the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) command transforms the resulting objects by replacing their property values with their `.value` property value.

`.psobject.Properties` is a way of reflecting on any object's properties, and each property-information object returned has a `.Name` and a `.Value` property.

[`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) converts the modified objects back to JSON

Given the following sample JSON input:

```json
[
  {
    "variables": {
      "appdata": {
        "value": "x1"
      },
      "appinsta": {
        "value": "y1"
      }      
    }   
  },
  {
    "variables": {
      "appdata": {
        "value": "x2"
      },
      "appinsta": {
        "value": "y2"
      }      
    }   
  }
]
```

the above outputs:

```json
[
  {
    "appdata": "x1",
    "appinsta": "y1"
  },
  {
    "appdata": "x2",
    "appinsta": "y2"
  }
]
```